# Me da el error "bash: python: orden no encontrada" en Sublime Text 3 de Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, rutas, sublimetext3, anaconda

Tengo algunos problemas al ejecutar un código fuente muy simple de python en sublime, he probado a correrlo en la terminal del sistema y ningún problema, pero si presiono `Ctrl+b` o `F7` me aparece en consola lo siguiente:

```
bash: python: orden no encontrada
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/user/Desktop/GUI/one.py"]
[dir: /home/user/Desktop/GUI]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

Pensé que tenía un problema en las variables del sistema (cosa que también podría ser), pero al parecer sublime utiliza la petición de shell como `python` y no `python3`, ya que en linux se escribe explícitamente así para la versión (creo), encontré la "solución" en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58127516/why-does-sublime-text-3-give-me-a-python-command-not-found-error/59827227#59827227?newreg=c72f71eb395741fa9031298669f768f4) de Stackoverflow.

Después de hacer algunas configuraciones funcionó, pero no como debería, quise utilizar el plugin Anaconda para agilizar en un futuro el desarrollo en python pero ... aparece otro error y esta vez en ventana.

[image: Mensaje del plugin Anaconda]

Ahora sí que estoy perdido ¿Tenéis alguna idea de porque sucede esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me aparecía el mismo error y logré solucionarlo de esta manera
Utilizando la línea de comando [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html)

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

y si sale un error "no hay alternativas para Pyhton" como en mi caso, introducir esta línea de comando.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

Lo que hace es que cambia la ruta de acceso `/usr/bin/python3` a la versión deseada.

---

---

Edit

Si no te llegase a funcionar Input() corre el archivo con SublimeREPL, si lo tienes instalado simplemente ve a Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python - RUN current file.

Si no lo tuvieses instalado, abre la paleta de comandos "command palette" presionando `Ctrl+Shift+P` y a continuación escribe `Install Package Control`.
Luego de esto escribes `Package Control: Install Package` y para finalizar `SublimeREPL`.